# oop design: returning a boolean property rather than explicitly returning TRUE or FALSE

Tags: php, oop

I have noticed that most PHP-based libraries or frameworks have classes that don't explicitly return the keywords TRUE and FALSE, instead:

```
if(condition)
{
  $this->boolean_property = FALSE;
  return $this->boolean_property
}
```

does this mean anything or is it just another "purist" move which does not present any advantage over the other approach?

here is another code from an authentication library:

```
protected $_logged_in = false;

public function is_logged_in()
{
 if (isset($_SESSION['userdata'])
 {
  $this->_logged_in = true;
 }
 return $this->_logged_in;
}
```

Comment: It looks like a degeneration of a holdover from a solution to a problem in PHP v4: if the function returned a reference, you had to return a variable. A constant wouldn't work, and neither would another function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example makes sense, probably the class is checking for the `$_logged_in` property at a latter stage.

The first one could be simplified to:

```
return $this->boolean_property = FALSE;
```

However it still seems stupid ***by itself***, and a simple `return false;` would be preferable.

Comment: will you give examples when "it" is not "by itself" and the approach would prove to be beneficial?

Comment: @Ygam: The only case where it would be beneficial to store the boolean in a object property (or variable for that matter) before returning is when you need to check for the result at a latter stage.

Answer (score 0):

It's still returning FALSE.  It's just also setting a instance field, presumably so you can query it later.  A real example might clarify things further.  Where did you see this code?